# Merge tags [apache] and [apache2]?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

We have two different tags for the Apache web server:

[apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache) (> 47,000 Questions tagged)

> The Apache HTTP Server, commonly referred to as Apache, is an open-source HTTP server for modern operating systems including UNIX, its variants and Windows. Apache is a secure, efficient and extensible server that provides HTTP services in sync with the current HTTP standards.

[apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache2) (> 4,000 Questions tagged)

> Apache (HTTP Server) /əˈpætʃiː/ is a modular cross-platform web server software with a large variety of features(called modules) including SSL, compression, log, proxy and server-side programming language interfaces like Perl, Python, Tcl, and PHP.

I think it's safe to assume that most of these Questions are about Apache 2.x because Apache 1.x hasn't been supported for several years. Should these tags be merged?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281651

Answer (score 7):

I support this synonymisation. Apache 2 has been out since 2001; it's reasonable to assume that we have no more than a dozen or so questions about Apache 1, if we have any at all.

Comment: The vast majority of the Apache questions I see aren't even programming related, they're about sysadmin things (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41552716/virtual-host-for-old-site-and-subdomains).  Unfortunately they often aren't a good fit for serverfault.com either because the questions are too simple for a "professional" sys-admin

Comment: @Alnitak Perhaps my background in small business (such that I've never had access to a professional sysadmin, honestly don't know what they do, and see server config as part of web development) biases me here, but I've never liked the sentiment against Apache config questions on Stack Overflow. We're happy to accept questions here about stuff like route configuration written in procedural code in web frameworks, but suddenly the same question becomes off-topic when the code is written in a markup language and handled directly by the server software? I've never seen the logic in that.

Comment: I'm thinking of stuff that isn't plain .htaccess, and especially when it involves things like appropriate DNS configuration, `<VirtualHost>` directives, etc.