# Make the [apache] tag more specific

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache) tag is very specifically [referring to](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apache/info)

> The Apache HTTP Server, commonly referred to as Apache, is an open-source HTTP server for modern operating systems including UNIX, its variants and Windows. Apache is a secure, efficient and extensible server that provides HTTP services in sync with the current HTTP standards.

Yet people use this frequently to form a tag-sentence containing other ASF projects, like in

- [`[apache] [maven]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache+maven)
- [`[apache] [hadoop]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache+hadoop)
- [`[apache] [storm]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache+storm)
- [`[apache] [camel]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache+camel)

just to mention a few, which is often against the intended scope of the tag. Since the ASF hosts quite a [number of projects](https://projects.apache.org/projects.html), one can imagine all the (im)possible tag combinations that are constructed each day.

**Proposal**

Rename the tag to [apache-httpd] or something more specific to prevent people from mis-using the tag.

Comment: Ah, there is already a similar proposal [over here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272457)

Comment: We haven't learn from apache pig...

Comment: @cybermonkey you definitivelly are very sensible and reading too much. "apache pig" is yet another [product of apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_%28programming_tool%29) which naming sense already caused [problems with one tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226637/213575). I´m pointing out that using the short version of the name, in this case just apache, can be ambigous like Apache Pig´s, [pig] tag did.

Comment: This would require askers to know that the Apache HTTP server is also known as httpd in order to tag their questions. Do they? I'd guess you'll lose 25% of potential askers just at that hurdle.

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well with another Apache project. I've been removing these tags as I see them, but renaming would probably eliminate the confusion.

Comment: What does it take to restart this discussion, or better follow up with action? The inadvertant tag-abuse by people who don't read the tag description is quite annoying

Answer (score 27):

You say:

> Rename the tag to [apache-httpd] or something more specific to prevent people from mis-using the tag.

I would **extend this to all tags of the apache family**. As we probably know of the Apache Foundation's (actually, programmers) weird naming scheme, it is better that we are proactive and use an unambigous [company-product] pair, to prevent these confusions.

Comment: Not so sure if we should extend it to all of them. First, things change. Next, we will end up with 245 (# of projects per above list) `[apache-something]` tags. Is that really what we want?

Comment: @JensG the Apache foundation has demonstrated that their naming scheme is very crappy. We have apache ant, pig, beehive, aries, bookkeeper, etc. which have their own meanings outside apache. By doing this we will be future proof in case other projects take similar naming.

Answer (score 8):

Many times in the past I've changed tags on Apache POI-related questions to remove the [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache) tag, which is irrelevant for [apache-poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-poi) questions.  We should rename [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache) to [apache-http-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-http-server), as it's commonly known.  Those questions about the HTTP Server can be retagged to [apache-http-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-http-server).  Questions not about the HTTP Server can have that tag removed from the question.

I would **prevent** the [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache) tag from being re-created; it's too general because Apache has so many relevant projects.  It doesn't make sense for someone to be an expert in "Apache" because that person is an expert in one particular Apache project.  For example, I know a lot about Apache POI, but not most Apache projects in general.

As far as those projects with no naming conflict, we can create tag synonyms.  The [apache-poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-poi) tag already has a [poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poi) synonym; synonyms can be created for those that don't have it already, e.g. "apache-project" for "project" or vice versa.

Comment: Prevent from being recreated - good idea, didn't know this is possible at all.

Answer (score 5):

One way to look at it is that the Apache Software Foundation has trademarks. In all cases, there is a mark, 'Apache X'. Like, 'Apache Pig'. In other cases, the Foundation also defends the trademark X, like 'Hadoop'.

This happens for the obvious reason: 'pig' is ambiguous, Hadoop is not. It would be least confusing to forbid 'apache' as a tag, and let individual products be apache-x or x depending on whether they are ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

- I think [apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache2) should refer to the web server. That also means all [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache) Questions should be re-tagged to [apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache2), if they refer to the server. ([inspiration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272457))
- The rest of the Question should be tagged `product` instead of `company-product` (e.g. [hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hadoop) instead of [apache-hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-hadoop)). The one exception is if there are conflicts, but I expect those to be at a minimum.