# Should I make a post about retagging if I can (and have) handled it as a sanity check for mods?

Tags: discussion, tags

So yesterday I noticed that there was a duplicate [jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jmeter) (3000+) questions tag called [apache-jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-jmeter) which had 50ish questions in it.

The second tag had the same wiki entry, and most questions were cross-tagged with the normal jmeter tag. I went ahead and retagged all of them and fixing any issues I found with them and went about my merry business without actually mentioning anything in meta.

[Here's the changes I made](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2958086/compass?tab=activity&sort=revisions&page=1). Goes to page 3.

My question is, in such a case where we *know* the tag is duplicate, and it's no biggie to do ourselves, do we need to post a `retag-request` for it for logging and moderation sanity purposes?

Comment: HOW DARE YOU DO SOMETHING LIKE THAT? You wanna be helpful or something? :O

Comment: @Patrice I am the monster MSO deserves, but not the one it needs. With great power comes great retaggability.

Comment: Now migrate most of them to http://sqa.stackexchange.com/ ;-)

Comment: For cases like this just make the tag a synonym rather than editing every single question.

Comment: @Servy I don't have enough rep by about 63 points to suggest synonyms =..= nor do I have a tag score of 5 =..=

Comment: @Compass Then request a mod make the synonym.

Comment: @Servy I went ahead and took care of it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In cases where it's more than a handful of questions (say, 20 or more), I'd write a quick Meta post before retagging, even in such clear cases. Someone else might notice something you didn't (most of the questions are off-topic and need to be closed, for example), or they might just pitch in and help you out.

You might want to suggest a synonym once you're done with the clean-up, so the removed tag doesn't pop up again. The example you gave is a good candidate for that, since those two tags mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: OK. Do I need to make one for jmeter for posterity's sake, now that I've already done it?

Comment: @Compass No, I don't think you need to. Unless you want some help retagging those last two [apache-jmeter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-jmeter) questions. ;)

Comment: Where did they come from?!

Comment: @Compass The old tag isn't completely burned from the system for about a day after you remove it, so anyone can still add it to any question.

Answer (score 9):

You absolutely should  always post first on Meta! This one in particular has a relevant request to move to the new tag name that you're thinking of deleting: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281675/1394393. How would you know which one to delete or if it makes sense to delete one without asking on meta? Or maybe there's an in progress request going on.

Comment: Now the synonym goes the other way...

Comment: @Deduplicator Exactly why a post should have been made prior to doing any of this.