# Synonymize [tomee] and [apache-tomee]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I was just reviewing suggested edits and I saw several edits that consisted in changing tags from [apache-tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-tomee) to [tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tomee) because the former has the following excerpt:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG! Please use [tomee] instead.

- [apache-tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-tomee) has almost 200 questions.
- [tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tomee) has almost 300 questions.

There is already a synonym suggestion on [apache-tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-tomee) but it has no votes (and I don't meet the requirements to vote either). As far as I understand it's unlikely to reach the required votes on a tag with only so few questions.

I suppose [tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tomee) can indeed be the master tag since there does not seem anything else with the same name.

Would it thus be possible to make [apache-tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-tomee) a synonym for [tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tomee)?

Comment: Every other apache related tag has the `apache-` prefix so for consistency the tag wiki should be edited and `apache2-tomee` should be the master. Unless I'm missing something special for this case?

Comment: Indeed I wasn't sure about that… However tags such as [tag:maven], [tag:ant] and [tag:tomcat] appear to be the master tag so I guess it would make sense to have the same for [tag:tomee].

Comment: Great - so pig, hive, kafka, spark, camel, storm and a couple of others use  the `apache-` prefix, and those you mention (and others) don't... Might be a larger debate than this specific instance as to what should be done here. Do they all get consistent prefixes, or do the "larger" projects not need them (or otherwise products were the prefix is definitely not required etc...)

Comment: [make the \[apache\] tag more specific](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281651/make-the-apache-tag-more-specific) also extends to the _apache- prefix_ question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The synonym for [tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tomee) was proposed long back on Apr 24 '14 by Jonathan S. Fisher, but wasn't approved. I approved the synonym proposal now, and they're synonyms, that is:

[apache-tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-tomee) (× 138) → [tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tomee) (× 748)

However, given the fact that most of the apache tags have a "apache-" prefix, I preferred to have the [apache-tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-tomee) as the master. The issue with that was, [tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tomee) had the better tag wiki. Therefore, to fix that, I had to merge [apache-tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-tomee) with [tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tomee), delete the synonym, and then rename the tag [tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tomee) to [apache-tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-tomee), and then finally, add [tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tomee) as a synonym to [apache-tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-tomee).