# Make tag synonyms: [tomee] and [apache-tomee]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Can someone make [tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tomee) and [apache-tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-tomee) synonyms?

There was some discussion 4 years ago: [Synonymize [tomee] and [apache-tomee]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311802/synonymize-tomee-and-apache-tomee), but 4 years later, the tag synonym suggestion still has 0 votes. Meanwhile the number of questions for [tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tomee) has increased to 700+ questions, while [apache-tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-tomee) has ~130 questions.

Rather than having a tag excerpt for [apache-tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-tomee) that currently says:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG! Please use [tomee] instead.

Why not just make them synonyms now?