# Merge [apache-http-server] tag into [apache]

Tags: discussion, tags

I believe that the [apache-http-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-http-server) tag should be made into a synonym of the [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache) tag for the following reasons:

- They are the same thing, refer to the same apache web server.
- [apache-http-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-http-server) is only used by 11 questions, as opposed to the ~77k tagged [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache).
- 5 of the questions tagged with [apache-http-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-http-server) are also tagged with [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache) anyway.

I also saw [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281651/4087397), but I believe in this case, the more popular [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache) tag should be used.

**Edit:** I have cleaned up and re-tagged all questions that had the [apache-http-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-http-server) tag as per [Bill the Lizard's suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360886/4087397). Hopefully it will quietly disappear from the tag list now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that those questions should be retagged, but I don't know if a synonym is called for yet. Once the [apache-http-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-http-server) tag is removed from those 11 questions, the tag will no longer be suggested by the UI (within 24 hours). If an incorrect tag keeps popping up, a synonym can be created.

Since there are such a small number of questions with the tag, you could go ahead and suggest edits removing them. Please make sure you [make *all other* necessary edits](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) to each question, as we don't generally like to bump questions to the review queues for one small change.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll fix them up and remove the tag.