# Rename [apache] to [apache-httpd]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I realize there was a [cleanup of the nascent [apache-http-server] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360883/merge-apache-http-server-tag-into-apache), but this is coming at it from the other end

[apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache) is too vague a tag now.

> Use this tag (along with an appropriate programming-language tag) for programming questions relating to the Apache HTTP Server. Do not use this tag for questions about other Apache Foundation products. Note that server configuration questions are usually a better fit on https://serverfault.com

Back in the day, almost all of Apache was [its web server (called httpd, or HTTP Daemon)](http://httpd.apache.org/), which is still the top web server on the Internet. It makes sense that the tag would become synonymous with that. But Apache can now also refer to [The Apache Software Foundation](http://apache.org/) which encompasses

> - 350+ Projects and Initiatives
> - 300+ Top-Level Projects
> - 52 podlings in the Apache Incubator

As such, people are now using this to refer to *any* Apache foundation project. For instance [this question about Apache PDFBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56544530/adding-header-to-footer-to-existing-pdf-using-apache-pdf-box-2-0-4) which uses [pdfbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdfbox) AND [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache). A rename to what most questions are using it for would solve the problem.

It would probably not be a bad idea to rename the following as well

- [apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache2) -> [apache-httpd2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-httpd2)
- [apache2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache2.2) -> [apache-httpd-2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-httpd-2.2)
- [apache2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache2.4) -> [apache-httpd-2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-httpd-2.4)

Comment: Wait, I remember that we disambiguated apache httpd webserver, since the project was taking other projects. I can't find the post right now, maybe in the other meta.

Comment: I can see the logic behind your main point, but renaming those last three would be a step backwards, since those are pretty un-ambiguous, and the shorter version is much closer to real-world usage.