# Synonymise [apache-echarts] with [echarts]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I just stumbled across [apache-echarts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-echarts), with 148 questions and no user guidance. There's also [echarts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/echarts) with 1349 questions and the excerpt:

> Apache ECharts is a free open-source charting and data visualization library written in JavaScript.(...)

So why do we have [apache-echarts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-echarts)? It seems that its scope is fully covered by [echarts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/echarts) already. Furthermore, 128 questions have both tags, leaving only 20 questions with only [apache-echarts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-echarts).

Should (or even can) we merge the two?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281651/make-the-apache-tag-more-specific – probably better to keep the one with the `apache-` prefix.

Comment: Does "echarts" even mean anything outside of the context of Apache ECharts?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel actually yes, but nothing at all the same as Apache ECharts. "[E charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_chart)" are probably most famously/widely shorthand for "Eye charts", the American (I think) pyramid-style charts of letters that ophthalmologists use to determine how poor your vision is.

Comment: @TylerH It's not a shorthand for "Eye charts". Those charts are called E charts, because they literally have a "E" and only a "E" in it(Snellen charts, on the other hand, have other characters and are more widely used). In any case, I don't see it  overlapping with programming.

Comment: @TheMaster I have definitely visited eye doctors who refer to them as "eye" charts. So maybe "Eye" is the colloquial "backronym" for E rather than the inverse. But that's getting rather into the weeds of the comment.

Answer (score 4):

If there are two tags that need to be synonymized or where one needs to be removed, we typically want to synonymize them so that the more descriptive tag is the parent/the one that remains.

Given both tags seem to be implicitly or explicitly about Apache ECharts, I think [apache-echarts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-echarts) should be the parent/target tag that remains here.