# Should we merge tags [ibatis] and [mybatis]?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Despite [MyBatis](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mybatis/info) being [technically a fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535900/difference-between-ibatis-and-mybatis) of [iBATIS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ibatis/info), practically speaking, from the user (developers) point of view, it was just a name change (a requirement for the project to left the Apache umbrella).

iBATIS development was effectively frozen, and the development team moved to MyBatis.  There were some differences in the transition, but not bigger than that of a typical version change (less differences that, say, [apache to apache2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272457/merge-tags-apache-and-apache2)).

Crucially, most of the knowledge that developers have left in SO regarding iBATIS applies to myBatis. And practically no one uses iBATIS today (or when they say they do, they mostly mean MyBatis).

Hence, I believe the tags should be merged. Or, more specifically, iBATIS should be a synonym of MyBatis.